# Get variable declared in another Screen

Tags: python, kivy

I am working on one simple Kivy GUI application. What i am trying to do is that i am want to access one object 'obj_random' of class 'CL_Random' from second screen(in which it is not created). I just don't know how to access declared in one screen to different screen.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
#from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
#from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class CL_FirstWindow(Screen):
    def change_screen(self):
        obj_random = CL_Random()
        self.parent.current = 'second_window'

class CL_SecondWindow(Screen):
    scond_prop = ObjectProperty(None)
    def change_screens(self):
        self.parent.current = 'first_window'

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class CL_Random:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

presentation = Builder.load_file("rough2.kv")

class app(App):
     def build(self):
        return presentation


obj_app = app()
obj_app.run()
```

**rough2.kv**

```
ScreenManagement:
    CL_FirstWindow:
    CL_SecondWindow:

<CL_FirstWindow>:
    id: first_window_id
    name: 'first_window'
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Button1'
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.12
            pos_hint: {'x':0.1,'y':0.6}
            on_release: root.change_screen()
<CL_SecondWindow>:
    id: second_window_id
    name: 'second_window'
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Button2'
            size_hint: 0.3, 0.12
            pos_hint: {'x':0.1,'y':0.6}
            on_release: root.change_screens()
        Label:
            id: second_label_id
            text: 'SECOND SCREEN'
            pos_hint: {'x': 0.20, 'y':0.8}
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            font_size: 35
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'
            text_size: self.size
```

Thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access a variable that is declared within a class the first thing is that this variable must be an attribute of the class so that the scope is greater, but as in your case the variable is local and it will be eliminated when it finishes executing the function.

On the other the solution is based on accessing the other Screen via the `ScreenManager`, and having the object access to the attribute for it we use the get_screen() method:

```
CL_SecondWindow --> ScreenManager --> CL_FirstWindow --> obj_random
```

---

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class CL_FirstWindow(Screen):
    def change_screen(self):
        self.obj_random = CL_Random()
        self.manager.current = 'second_window'

class CL_SecondWindow(Screen):
    scond_prop = ObjectProperty(None)
    def change_screens(self):
        first_screen = self.manager.get_screen('first_window')
        print(first_screen.obj_random.x)

        self.parent.current = 'first_window'

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

class CL_Random:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

presentation = Builder.load_file("rough2.kv")

class app(App):
     def build(self):
        return presentation


obj_app = app()
obj_app.run()
```